# FadeIn javascript function in Safari not working but FadeOut works :(

Tags: javascript, safari, opacity, fadein, fadeout

So I've made  custom function for a game I'm working on, one being fade in the other one fade out. The problem is fadeOut works, but fading back IN does not... strange. Any clues? See code below.

THIS WORKS:

```
fadeOut:function(o,duration)
{
    o.style.opacity = 1;
    o._anim = function()
    {
         if(o.style.opacity <=0)
         {
             clearInterval(o._animInt);
             return false;
         }
         o.style.opacity -= .1;
         game.log("opacity:" + o.style.opacity);
    }
    o._animInt = setInterval(o._anim,duration / 10)
}
```

THIS DOES NOT:

```
fadeIn:function(o,duration)
{
    o.style.opacity = 0;
    o._anim = function()
    {
        if(o.style.opacity >= 1)
        {
            clearInterval(o._animInt);
            return false;
        }
        o.style.opacity += .1;
        game.log("opacity:" + o.style.opacity);
    }
    o._animInt = setInterval(o._anim,duration / 10)
}
```

Comment: does the `game.log` show the the increments ?

Comment: ah yes, forgot to mention that. yes it's just like console.log ... a custom log function i made. So during fade out, the opacity decrements appropriately. but on fade it, it stays at .1 and loops infinitely.

Comment: Have you tried using a double for opacity ? `if(o.style.opacity >= 1.0)`

Comment: Does it work in any other browsers?  You may want to add the bit about "Stays at .1" to the question.  I missed it at first.

Comment: Well as the fadeOut method works, and the logger is picking up the increments, its the `o.style.opacity += .1;` thats not registering !

Comment: Note: you should also use `o.filters.alpha.opacity=X` for IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function fadeIn (o,duration) {
   o.style.opacity = 0;

   o._anim = function() {
      var opacity = parseFloat(o.style.opacity);
      if(opacity >= 1) { clearInterval(o._animInt); return false;}
      o.style.opacity = opacity + 0.1;
      game.log("opacity:" + o.style.opacity);
   }

   o._animInt = setInterval(o._anim,duration / 10)
}
```

The opacity attribute is a string. Parse it first, compare, increment, then store. This worked for me in Chrome and Firefox.